# I have a JQuery Dialog being displayed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a Jquery Dialog being displayed  .on the Top of the dialog i have Two Elements appearing on the top of the dialog .How to hide this two elements .Iam Getting this issue in IE6.0 and IE 8.0 it works fine

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot? For now I cannot figer out what elements you want to hide.

Comment: We need more info. Any code, screen grabs, recreate the issue at jsbin or jsfiddle. There is nothing to go on here!

Comment: What version of jQuery/jQuery UI are you using? It sounds like you're using one from before bigiframe was added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to hide the select Elements under the dialog This doesniot happen in IE6.0 and works fine in IE8